# Create a filter on a column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I currently have a file with data that looks like this.

[image]

I am trying to get it to look like this.

[image]

All I need is the filter added. I need to have this filter created in Python but I am not sure how. I do not need to go through Pandas and I have tried openpyxl. My caveat is that I am not currently filtering anything. I just need the filter to be present for others to use.

Comment: yeah, and like I mentioned, I just need the filter. I tried using the open pyxl filter and it gives me an error because the value must be a sequence. However, I am not trying to filter at this time, simply having the filter.

Comment: the link @sunnytown sent, just shows me how I can filter certain words/items. That is not what I need done here. I am simply trying to create the filter here without having to have existing words/items to filter. This way, when someone else goes into the workbook they can do that themself.

Comment: As the page says, Openpyxl cannot be used to perform the actual filtering operation but just to setup the filter. Also, if you get a specific error, feel free to post your code so that you can get some actual help.

Comment: You were right @sunnytown, my apologies. I must have missed that in the documentation portion. It works now! Very much appreciated. I will go ahead and post my solution

Comment: Glad it worked out. Sorry for my passive aggressive tone though.

Answer (score 1):

For the solution, I followed openpyxl's documentation and used this to create a filter by Batch Number.

```
ws.auto_filter.ref = 'A:A'
ws.auto_filter.add_filter_column(0,["Batch IDS"])
```

This worked for me! Hope it helps someone else.
**Openpyxl does not filter for you just creates the filter**